# determining frequency in given time in java

Tags: java, audio, fft

Determining a FFT(Fast Fourier Transformation) is often time-frequency trade off. If we calculate FFT over larger time(15 to 20 seconds), we can get more accurate frequencies but very less number of them. For smaller time intervals frequencies often show sharp variations.
What is the best time interval in which we can have a reliable data with sufficient number of frequency points?

Comment: "sufficient number of frequency points" -- sufficient for what?

Comment: sufficient to match two samples.. thanks for pointing out that..:)

Comment: In theory, as you increase the number of samples you process, you improve the accuracy, with the only "cost" being processing time/space.  If you need more frequent measurements, use a sliding window, where you process, say, an 8000 sample "window" every 2000 samples, reprocessing some samples (6000) you've already processed.  The "right" time interval, though, is the one that best suits your needs, could be 10 times a second, could be 10 times a minute.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your type of audio. Maybe you should consider using a Wavelet analysis. With this you can extract very accurate high frequencies without loosing the recognition of low frequencies.

Comment: I am taking input from a mic.. The audio format is:
float sampleRate = 44100;
int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
int channels = 1;
     boolean signed = true;
     boolean bigEndian = true;

Comment: Is'nt something like a 1sec FFT giving you everything that human can hear (2Hz to 22,5Khz) ? After that, you *mix* the results of the 1sec ffts. ..or am I completely wrong ? I don't see the problem (except for the low-amplitude noise, which I think you can reduce by others means)

Answer (score 1):

have a read of the [Nysquist-Shannon Sampling Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) - sampling at 1/2B where B is the maximum frequency in the signal should give you the ability to reconstruct it without data loss.

This implies to me that you could get a good enough FFT for a signal by sampling for twice the period of the minimum frequency in the sample - that is, I guess, if the sample is periodic :P

Comment: When B is the maximum frequency, you need at least twice its size, not half.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" depends on your needs.

If time resolution is more important then a smaller number of points may be better.

If frequency resolution is more important than a larger number of points may be better.

If the noise floor is high, then even more points may be better.

If you don't care about either, then use a short FFT to save on compute time and energy.  (Or don't bother with the FFT and just take some results from /dev/random).

If the signals of interest are not stationary (e.g. they change over time), then you may want an FFT short enough to separate all the individual spectral events of interest each into their own FFT window.

If you need frequency resolution that can clearly separate a spectral signal peak from adjacent noise peaks, then you want an FFT length of around at least twice the sample rate divided by the minimum delta frequency between the peaks you want separated, more if you window.  If you don't need this accuracy then a shorter FFT will do.

If the noise level and the interference is low enough compared to your signal(s) of interest, you might be able to interpolate frequency estimates from isolated peaks with a much shorter FFT, or even without an FFT.  As little as 3 or 4 non-aliased sample points might do for a single sinusoid in zero noise.